# Moving data from backup to the current data table

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I need to add some backup data to the current data table

Something like

```
INSERT INTO `gts`.`Events`
(`accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime`)
VALUES (SELECT `accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime` 
FROM `historic`.`BD_01`
WHERE accountID='0001' AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01 00:00:00')
AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-31 23:59:59'));
```

But I'm getting an error around SELECT.
What I'm doing wrong?

The backup data table has less columns than the current data table, that's why I specify what columns I'm using.

Some register can be duplicated, Should I use REPLACE INTO instead?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `VALUES` keyword. It should just be `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`. Your query should look like

```
INSERT INTO `gts`.`Events`
(`accountID`,
`deviceID`,
`timestamp`,
`statusCode`,
`latitude`,
`longitude`,
`gpsAge`,
`speedKPH`,
`heading`,
`inputMask`,
`odometerKM`,
`creationTime`)
SELECT `accountID`,
`deviceID`,
`timestamp`,
`statusCode`,
`latitude`,
`longitude`,
`gpsAge`,
`speedKPH`,
`heading`,
`inputMask`,
`odometerKM`,
`creationTime` 
FROM `historic`.`BD_01`
WHERE accountID='0001' 
AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01 00:00:00')
AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-31 23:59:59');
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is any unique key and there is chance of duplicate then there can be 2 conditions-

If you want to override data from backup then use below query-

```
REPLACE INTO `gts`.`Events`
(`accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime`)
SELECT `accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime` 
FROM `historic`.`BD_01`
WHERE accountID='0001' AND TIMESTAMP > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01 00:00:00') AND TIMESTAMP < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-31 23:59:59');
```

If you want to keep old value and insert only new entry then use below query-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `gts`.`Events`
(`accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime`)
SELECT `accountID`,`deviceID`,`timestamp`,`statusCode`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsAge`,`speedKPH`,`heading`,`inputMask`,`odometerKM`,`creationTime` 
FROM `historic`.`BD_01`
WHERE accountID='0001' AND TIMESTAMP > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-01 00:00:00') AND TIMESTAMP < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-31 23:59:59');
```